# C# - Getting UnauthorizedAccessException on created Directory

Tags: c#, file-permissions, sharpdevelop, writefile

On my application i have a Config-FileReader - These checks on Startup, if a `Temp` directory (on applications folder, here the configuration will be stored as `Config.json`) exists, otherwise the application will create it. These steps works for a long time correctly.

After few days development, i had today create a simple File-Downloader:

```
    public static void Download(string url, string destination, Callback OnSuccess) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[Download] " + url + " to " + destination + " (" + Utils.getFileName(url) + ")");
        using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = Software.getName() + "/" + Software.getVersion() + " (" + Software.getOSVersion() + "; " + Software.getOSBit() + "; " + Software.getOSVersionFull() + ")";

                client.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    var text = e.Result;
                    File.WriteAllText(destination, Path.Combine(destination, Utils.getFileName(url)));
                    OnSuccess((Object) Path.Combine(destination, Utils.getFileName(url)));
                };
                client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url));
            }
    }
```

When i try to download a file to the previous created `Temp` directory, an `UnauthorizedAccessException` comes up. Curiously is: The directory was created successfully by the application and the config file will be created/readed/writed.

But when i try to download a file:

```
API.Download(media.URL, Software.getPath() + "Temp", OnSuccess);
```

Debug-Output of the Downloader:

> [Download] https://c-ash.smule.com/sf/s26/arr/88/4e/48afbe6c-9aeb-4cc7-82cf-e04d5f0d6b44.mp3 to C:\Users\info\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\SongManager\SongManager\bin\Debug\Temp (48afbe6c-9aeb-4cc7-82cf-e04d5f0d6b44.mp3)

i't gives an `UnauthorizedAccessException`:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the Path "C:\Users\info\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\SongManager\SongManager\bin\Debug\Temp" was denied.

**Edit**

The same problem appears, when i use another directory, which will created live before the download starts.

**Edit 2**

My second thinks are, thats an Threading problem, because `DownloadDataAsync` running on another thread. But an

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate {
    File.WriteAllText(destination, Path.Combine(destination, Utils.getFileName(url)));
}));
```

won't fix the problem.

Comment: The same - Here i have already tried to run the application with higher privileges (as Administrator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I call shenanigans

[File.WriteAllText Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Parameters**
>
> - path
>
>   - Type: System.String
>   - The file to write to.
> - contents
>
>   - Type: System.String
>   - The string to write to the file.

**Your Code**

```
client.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
         {
            var text = e.Result;
            // look at your parameters 
            File.WriteAllText(destination, Path.Combine(destination, Utils.getFileName(url)));
            OnSuccess((Object)Path.Combine(destination, Utils.getFileName(url)));
         };
```

You are calling `File.WriteAllText` on a directory, and passing the combined path as the contents.

The error should be,

> "Step away from the keyboard young jedi and make your self a coffee! A directory is not a file and you have no business writing to one"